# Get tensor (or ndarray) of zeros, with ones at certain indices

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, torch

I need an efficient (emphasis on efficient) way to generate a tensor of zeros, with ones at all indices specified by a python list.

For instance, given the list [1, 3] I want a torch tensor `res` of shape (5) with:

```
res = torch.Tensor([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

In reality I have a list of lists [[1, 3], [2], ...] and I need a tensor of the form

```
res = torch.Tensor(
    [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     ...,
    ]
)
```

My idea was to solve the former problem and use torch.stack. I must stress that I am trying to make this as efficient as possible (it is currently a bottleneck in my code).

Comment: you might also want to look at  [torch.sparse_coo_tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html#construction)